# MySQL Create table syntax error

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE plan 
  ( 
     id                VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
     name              VARCHAR(20), 
     amount            INT, 
     interval          INT, 
     currency          CHAR(3), 
     object            VARCHAR(20), 
     livemode          BOOLEAN, 
     interval_count    INT, 
     trial_period_days INT, 
     created           TIMESTAMP, 
     updated           TIMESTAMP, 
     deleted           TIMESTAMP, 
     PRIMARY KEY (id) 
  );
```

Produces

```
'ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'interval          INT, 
     currency          CHAR(3), 
     object            ' at line 6'
```

Doesn't work. However if the 'l' at the end of 'interval' is removed. It works.

```
CREATE TABLE plan 
  ( 
     id                VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
     name              VARCHAR(20), 
     amount            INT, 
     interva           INT, 
     currency          CHAR(3), 
     object            VARCHAR(20), 
     livemode          BOOLEAN, 
     interval_count    INT, 
     trial_period_days INT, 
     created           TIMESTAMP, 
     updated           TIMESTAMP, 
     deleted           TIMESTAMP, 
     PRIMARY KEY (id) 
  );
```

I don't understand if this is a problem with attempting to use 'interval' and 'interval_count'. What's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "interval" is a reserved word. You can still use it if you quote it correctly.

See the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) for a list of the reserved words and how to use them.
In fact, "interval" is the first example in the link provided:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE interval (begin INT, end INT);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax ...
near 'interval (begin INT, end INT)'

mysql> CREATE TABLE `interval` (begin INT, end INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```